# Gravity form Razorpay payment gateway Email Notification

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, gravity-forms-plugin, razorpay

I am using Razor pay Gravity form plugin, After submit the gravity form, (before payment with Razor Pay) I am getting a email notification, Can some one please help me I need Email Notification only after Successful Payment.

Thank You.

Comment: Well, I need the same. Contacted Razorpay support and they gave vague replies. I don't think they will fix the problem. I've informed them many times. I'm also trying to fix the problem myself but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Goto gravity form Notification settings, under event, set the second option i.e Payment completed. You will receive an email notification once payment is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a better version of the plugin with the event notification and some other features which you can check here: https://github.com/isaumya/razorpay-gravity-forms-updated